# How to enable special key

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, wacom, xinput

I have a Wacom Cintiq 24HD tablet/screen which has several sets of buttons. Most of them work fine [edit: and are configurable with xsetwacom], but there's one set of buttons (touch buttons, actually) on the top of the screen which won't fully register in the Ubuntu GUI stack.

[Picture of the buttons in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVh6b.jpg)

Take the leftmost of the three buttons, the one labeled *`I`*. If I just press it, nothing happens. If I use `xev`, the button does not trigger any output (as opposed to the working buttons), but both `sudo showkey` and `sudo evtest` do indeed show that the button registers in the kernel (I suppose). I've identified the keycode as `202`:

```
% sudo evtest /dev/input/event4
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x56a product 0xf4 version 0x110
Input device name: "Wacom Cintiq 24HD Pad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
    Event code 202 (KEY_PROG3)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 257 (BTN_1)
    Event code 258 (BTN_2)
    Event code 259 (BTN_3)
    Event code 260 (BTN_4)
    Event code 261 (BTN_5)
    Event code 262 (BTN_6)
    Event code 263 (BTN_7)
    Event code 264 (BTN_8)
(output trimmed)
Event: time 1477672672.059563, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 202 (KEY_PROG3), value 1
Event: time 1477672672.059563, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 40 (ABS_MISC), value 15
Event: time 1477672672.059563, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1477672672.291614, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 202 (KEY_PROG3), value 0
Event: time 1477672672.291614, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 40 (ABS_MISC), value 0
Event: time 1477672672.291614, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

`showkey` agrees with `evtest` that the keycode is `202`:

```
% sudo showkey -k
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode 202 press
keycode 202 release
```

However, I want to actually  use the button for something, so if I try to temporarily assign the button to the key 'a' for testing purposes, it does not seem to work.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 202 = a"
```

No 'a' is output if I press the button when in, say, a terminal emulator.

Am I doing something wrong with xmodmap, or is there some other tool I can use in order to make stuff happen when I press this button? I ultimately want the button to trigger a script, but if I can do that indirectly by remapping the button to some other key with modifiers, that's also great. Right now I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Use xsetwacom:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration

(see "man xsetwacom" too)

Find your device with

```
xsetwacom list
```

Example output:

```
Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad               id: 12  type: PAD       
Wacom DTK2241 Pen stylus            id: 13  type: STYLUS    
Wacom DTK2241 Pen eraser            id: 14  type: ERASER
```

My device was a DTK2241 so I'll use this example below:

```
xsetwacom -s get "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" all
```

Then for the pad device list your available buttons with:

```
xsetwacom -s get "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" all
```

Example output:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "1" "button +1 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "2" "+2 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "3" "+3 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "8" "+8 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "9" "+9 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "10" "+10 "
....
```

Then set a button, for example:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom DTK2241 Pad pad" "Button" "1" "key a"
```

Comment: I do this for the other buttons, but unfortunately this tool doesn't seem to register those three touch buttons on the top of the screen. Actually, for a long time I assumed that they didn't register with the kernel driver at all, but it seems they do. They seem to get lost somewhere in the stack, though, so tools like xsetwacom won't let me configure them. I should have mentioned this in my question.